# Django: Is there a way to cancel an receiver triggering for a particular model signal?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

I have a `post_save` signal receiver for a model in my domain. This receiver is triggered by many routines that run a save on that model (therefore I can't delete that receiver yet).

```py
@receiver(signal=post_save, sender=OrderGroup)
def check_commission_should_be_synced(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    # Receiver procedure
    # ...
```

I would like to cancel its triggering for a particular method that manipulates my model. Is that possible?

I'm using `Django 1.7` with `Python 2.7`.

Comment: Can you show us the models, the signal, and the method that you refer to?

Comment: Hey @CalebGoodman I updated the code adding the receiver. But I don't think it's necessary to add the rest of the code since my post was a generic question about a Django feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a non-database Boolean attribute to your model defaulting to False, like:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # existing datanase fields
    trigger_post_save = False
```

and for the methods you don't want to trigger post_save, set it to True before save:

```
my_instance.trigger_post_save = True
my_instance.save()
```

Finally, in your decorated method check the value and return if it's set:

```
@receiver(signal=post_save, sender=OrderGroup)
def check_commission_should_be_synced(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if instance.trigger_post_save:
        return
    # the rest of code
```

Comment: Nice idea! I will do that but I will set the flag to True by default, so I don't have to refactor all places where the model instances are saved. Thank you!